# gmap v3 api get polyline vertex and edge without set polyline editable

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

I have a polyline object compounded of some few thousand records(between 1000 - 4000). I need that every time that the 'mouseover' event is fired up over the polyline get the edge or the vertex number. Actually I'm available to get this data, but only if I set the polyline property 'editable' to true, the requirement is that the users can't edit the trip(polyline). The reason why I need this is because when I get the vertex or edge I use that number to get data from a array with all the locations that compound the polyline path and other parameters attached to each location(custom info, description, hour, etc), so when a polyline section is 'mouseovered' it get the information of the array based on the vertex/edge number and display a popup with the data.

I tried adding a marker for each location with a transparent image, so when the mouse is over the marker display the popup. The issue with it is when I get trips with more than 1000 locations the draw of the items is terrible slowed down(10 or 15 seconds to draw everything). Same happens if in the 'mouseover' event I got the latLng property and try to compare with a location from the array, because are to much locations and in some cases(slow browsers) get stuck when it's comparing the points.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
Break up your single polyline composed of 1000 to 4000 points into n polylines such that the first polyline's endpoint is the second polyline's starting point and so on until you have drawn n polylines that look identical to a single polyline drawn with all the points.

Now when you mouseover the polyline (composed of multiple polylines) you only have to iterate through the locations of one sub-polyline instead of all the locations of the compounded polyline (made up of the n sub-polylines).

How does this help?  If you pick n=10, then in your example above you only have to iterate over 100 to 400 points instead of 1000 to 4000 points to find the best match that is the location you are hovering over.  If n=10 is still too slow on some browsers, then pick n=20 or n=50. Goolgle Maps API is doing the work of narrowing it down to the sub-polyline so you get to skip iterating over the locations of the the other n-1 sub-polylines.

I have run into the same problem in an application I have, but I already had many separate polylines and need to find the location just as you had above. These polylines cannot be editable and so I will need to implement the search part as you describe at the end of your question and that is included as part of the solution I am suggesting for your particular problem.